# Set _NET_WM_NAME to the currently running command in Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, xorg, window-title

I am on Arch linux with X and dwm. I want to have the title of the window in st, the suckless terminal, to reflect the command I am running, instead of a plain st. For example if I am running htop to monitor my cpu usage, I want the title to be htop - st. How would I do this?

Edit: I would like this to be handled by my Xorg server rather than trap a function on a terminal being opened

Answer (score 1):

Just like in [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-2.FB9) or most other terminal emulators:

```
printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' whatever
```

The rest is up to the shell -- for instance, in bash you can use a `DEBUG` trap:

```
set_title(){
   local cmd=$BASH_COMMAND
   case $cmd in
   fg) cmd=$(jobs %); cmd=${cmd##"${cmd%  *}  "};;
   fg\ *|%*) cmd=$(jobs "${cmd#fg }"); cmd=${cmd##"${cmd%  *}  "};;
   esac
   printf '\e]2;%s\e\\' "${TERM%%-*} ${cmd//[$'\e\a']/#}"
}
trap set_title DEBUG
```

---

Setting just that window property could also be done with:

```
xprop -id "$WINDOWID" -f _NET_WM_NAME 8u -set _NET_WM_NAME whatever
```

but that wouldn't work reliably from within su, ssh, screen, tmux, etc.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, this just shows me how to change the value once, where I want the title to update as I run different commands

Comment: Yes it DOES answer your question, and yes I have tested it in `st`. The bash commands will AUTOMATICALLY change the title to "st - *last_command*" in `st`. If you're using another shell than `bash`, mention which one. If for some reason it doesn't work *with bash* on your machine, say "it doesn't seem to work with bash version x.x and with `set -x` it seems to be doing this and this", or "that command is broken because X and Y", etc. If for some other reason you do not like this answer (e.g. you do not understand what those commands are doing, but would not admit it), then just ignore it.

Comment: I saw what I was doing wrong, however, I would like this to be handled by my Xorg server, but I did not clarify that in my question, I will do so. With your solution this would work if I added your lines to my `~/.bashrc`, it's just not what I am looking for.

Comment: That is handled by your Xorg server; no program can change any window property without the involvement of the Xorg server. If you think that calling  `xprop -id $WINDOWID` directly from the trap is better: it's not because it will not work from ssh, etc.

Comment: tl;dr; I will not delete this answer; (I even think of improving it by having it set the title to the foreground process of tty instead of the last command entered). If you don't like it, **ignore it**.

Comment: Have you tried `xttitle`?

Comment: @waltinator `xttitle` is in no way any better than the `printf` oneliner from my answer. In fact, notice that my `DEBUG` handler is sanitizing the title --by replacing the `\e`s and `\a`s which could be used to *split* that escape and do *more* than set the title -- something that `xttitle` is not doing.