# Converting a bash script to use in zsh

Tags: shell-script, zsh

The following bash script was posted in this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616676/set-net-wm-name-to-the-currently-running-command-in-linux#) as a means of setting an ST (terminal window's) title in DWM (X window manager). While adding this segment to by .bashrc has the desired result, I would like to be able to use this in zsh.

```
set_title(){
   local cmd=$BASH_COMMAND
   case $cmd in
   fg) cmd=$(jobs %); cmd=${cmd##"${cmd%  *}  "};;
   fg\ *|%*) cmd=$(jobs "${cmd#fg }"); cmd=${cmd##"${cmd%  *}  "};;
   esac
   printf '\e]2;%s\e\\' "${TERM%%-*} ${cmd//[$'\e\a']/#}"
}
trap set_title DEBUG
```

I have already tried calling it as a bash script in my .zshrc, however this does not change the window title as expected. Any help converting this for use in zsh would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Could be something like:

```
TRAPDEBUG() {
  [[ $zsh_eval_context[1] = toplevel ]] || return
  local cmd=$ZSH_DEBUG_CMD
  case $cmd in
    (fg)
      cmd=$jobtexts[${(k)jobstates[(r)*:+:*]}];;
    (('fg '|%)<->)
      cmd=$jobtexts[${(M)cmd%%<->}];;
  esac
  printf '\e]2;%s\e\\' "${TERM%%-*} ${cmd//[$'\e\a']/#}"
}
```